# Need to take node value between two nodes

Tags: xslt

I have to apply templates for the node present in between two nodes

Ex..

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00EF034A" w:rsidRDefault="00360D3B">
<w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/>
<w:r>
<w:t>Comments</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:rStyle w:val="CommentReference"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:commentReference w:id="0"/>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

i have to apply-templates for the nodes present in between `commentRangeStart` and `commentRangeEnd`. Please help me in writing xslt template. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear if you want to **select** these nodes or you want to **match** them (as in a pattern). Also, there is a lot of answer about this grouping task...

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, one-liner solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a simple XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0) solution in addition to the complete answer of Dr. Kay**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:w="w:w">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "*/w:p/w:commentRangeStart[@w:id=0]
          /following-sibling::node()
              [following-sibling::w:commentRangeEnd[@w:id=0] ]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped into a top element, to be well-formed):

```
<t  xmlns:w="w:w">
    <w:p w:rsidR="00EF034A" w:rsidRDefault="00360D3B">
        <w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Comments</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="CommentReference"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:commentReference w:id="0"/>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result (applying the identity template to the selected nodes) is produced**:

```
<w:r xmlns:w="w:w">
   <w:t>Comments</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Comment: @vignesh: I am glad my solution was useful. May be you are not aware that at SO gratitude is expressed by accepting or upvoting an answer? Hint: you can accept an answer by clicking on the green check-mark next to it.

Comment: Glad to receive your reply Dimitre. I am stuck in converting listing in docx file to html(tough in maintaining the list order if it has image and table in between).Do you have any xsl templates to perform the operation.it will be really a useful one for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vignesh: No, I have never done such conversion. Why you just don't save the files to html format using Word's "Save as" command?

Comment: @Dimitre:ya thats possible..but i get the document on the fly..so have to do conversion via xslt and produce the output..

Comment: @vignesh: Even if you get the documents on the fly, you could still use Word automation and make the Word objects programatically save the document as html. Not that I am against doing this with XSLT -- just another possible approach.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're dealing with parallel/overlapping markup, where the "commentrangestart" and "commentrangeend" elements act as "milestone" tags. There's an extensive literature on handling overlapping markup, and it would be worth your while to spend some time studying the subject.

The details depend a little on whether there is only one commentrange within a parent element, whether the range always starts and ends within the same element, and so on.

In XSLT 2.0 you can often handle such constructs using `<xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="commentrangestart">` or `<xsl:for-each-group group-ending-with="commentrangeend">`. You can also use the << and >> operators, for example `<xsl:for-each select="*[. &gt;&gt; $start and . &lt;&lt; $end]">`.

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0 it's a lot more difficult, but not impossible. The technique to use (which is worth learning because it's also useful with XSLT 2.0) is called "sibling recursion". You write a template that matches the commentrangestart element and does `<xsl:apply-templates mode="sibling" select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>`; you have two template rules in mode="sibling", one which matches the commentrangeend element and terminates the recursion, the other processes the elements in between, and concludes by doing a recursive call `<xsl:apply-templates mode="sibling" select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>`

Comment: @vignesh: In addition to Dr. Michael Kay complete explanation, there is other technique in XSLT 1.0 using keys: declaring a key value as preceding and following marks with `fn:generate-id()` and retriving those nodes when matching starting mark.